# Scala list of lists to array of arrays and vice versa

Tags: arrays, scala, list

I have a list of lists:

```
val l = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5), List(6, 7, 8))
```

I would like to turn it into an array of arrays, so I get:

```
val a = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5), Array(6, 7, 8))
```

Is there a more concise way for achieving this than:

```
l map (_.toArray) toArray
```

Likewise, is there a more concise way for obtaining a list of list from `a` than this:

```
a map (_.toList) toList
```

Thank you for advices

Comment: Looks pretty concise (and clear) to me already! Unless you're code-golfing, why do you need something more concise? If you're using it a lot, make it a method, maybe?

Comment: how can there be more concise way than this - `l.map(_.toArray).toArray` ? Its like asking about the most concise way to count from 1 to 10. It is to simply count from 1 to 10. You can not go shorter than that.

Comment: Scala surprised me many times with its idioms so I thought there might a standard function for converting two-dimensional data structures like the ones above. There are such functions for some cases, i.e. `transpose`